# Collapsed block icon changed

Tags: visual-studio-2022

Recently updated Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2022 (64-bit) to Version 17.9.0.
In the C/C++ editor, the collapsed block icon changed from "+" and "-" to ">" and "v".
Is there a way to get back to "+" and "-"?

Comment: Nope, it's baked in to the UI, you'll just need to live with it. More UI changes to come in 17.10.0, enjoy...

Comment: That's a pity, I also like the +/- more...

Comment: I seen some request in the community to change this or provide settings to change it. Hopefully it goes through because these carets are just more difficult to track with the eye

Comment: I also prefer the +/- icons. Hope to be able to choose it from some settings page.

Comment: Another change for the worse by the Visual Studio team, while other bugs that have been plaguing the product for years get ignored.

Comment: This sadly aligned with Visual Studio Code but it's not desirable.